# more elegant way to initialize range of array elements

Tags: java

It's been a couple years since I've done any java. I'm thinking there's a nicer way to write this, not sure how to google the question really.

```
boardSpots[0][1] = new Pawn();
boardSpots[1][1] = new Pawn();
boardSpots[2][1] = new Pawn();
boardSpots[3][1] = new Pawn();
boardSpots[4][1] = new Pawn();
boardSpots[5][1] = new Pawn();
boardSpots[6][1] = new Pawn();
boardSpots[7][1] = new Pawn();
```

Comment: Can't you create them in a loop?

Comment: Delete the question? :P

Comment: Too late now, I'll just have to deal with the shame

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    boardSpots[i][1] = new Pawn();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a nested `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < boardSpots.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < boardSpots[i].length; j++) {
        boardSpots[i][j] = new Pawn();
    }
}
```

[Check this great source out on loops in Java.](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/Looping/NestedFor.htm)